# Excel 2013 IF with wildcard

Tags: excel, if-statement

Need to put a "yes" in column AP if there is anything in cell U12 that starts with and "A".  I cant get a wildcard to work with the IF statement.

Example "A-1710" in U12 places a Yes in AP12

I've tried both

```
=IF(U12="A?", "Yes", "No")
=IF(U12="A*", "Yes", "No")
```

Probably a simple answer, but my brain is fried right now.
Thank You

Comment: Sorry, I figured out the problem with the IF statement and wildcards.  I used a COUNTIF instead.  Thank You

Answer (score 2):

You can probably use `LEFT` to get the answer.

```
IF(LEFT(U12,1)="A", "YES", "NO")
```

Answer (score 1):

`IF` would only return true if your cell were an exact match to `"A*"` (not a pattern match). You can get the desired behavior by using `COUNTIF` to do the matching part.

```
=IF(COUNTIF(U12, "A*") > 0, "Yes", "No")
```